# Windows10、IE11の環境にて、ASP.NET(C#)のコードよりPDF出力

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows10、IE11の環境にて、ASP.NET(C#)よりPDFファイルを「Adobe Acrobat Reader DC」で起動したいのですが、
以下のコードを処理してもPDF出力がされず、タスクマネージャーのバッググラウンドプロセスに「Adobe Acrobat Reader DC」のプロセスが2つ発生します。
何が原因でしょうか？

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile("c:\\temp\\test.pdf");
Response.End();
```

※ちなみに、MicrosoftEdgeでは、Edge画面にPDF出力しています。
また、Windows7、IE11の環境では、「Adobe Acrobat Reader DC」でPDF出力されます。

また、Windows10、IE11の環境にて、ASP.NET(C#)の以下のコードを処理した場合、EXCEL出力されます。

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.WriteFile("c:\\temp\\test.xlsx");
Response.End();
```

Comment: [マルチポスト](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/0f56dade-ea81-4f38-9051-2638f836c886/windows10ie11aspnetcpdf?forum=internetexplorerja)です。質問者さんは[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/4236)を確認してください。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: マルチポストであり、質問者は本スレッドを見ていないため。少なくとも他サイトで回答がついています。